# Prevent Whitespaces from Wysiwyg Input

Tags: php, web-applications, ckeditor

I have CKEditor embedded in my page. I need to prevent plain whitespaces and breaklines that doesn't come with any characters. There must be at least one actual visible character.

**The following answer is totally not consistent, sometimes it works fine and sometimes it does nothing, it allows whitespaces:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['rtxt_article']))
{
    if (trim(strip_tags($_POST['rtxt_article']))) {
      // do something
    }
    else
    {
      //ops! please fill in data
    } 
}
else
{
   //ops! please fill in data
}
```

**I also tried this:**

```
$plainText = strip_tags($_POST['rtxt_offer']);
$isNotEmpty = trim($plainText);
if($isNotEmpty)
{
   //do something
}
```

**When the above snippet doesn't have effect anymore, i put ! sign and the snippet works again. After a while, the snippet doesn't work until i remove ! and vice versa. Totally inconsistent. This is how i put !:**

```
if(!$isNotEmpty) ...
if (!trim(strip_tags($_POST['rtxt_article']))) ...
```

Any idea? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot.  It will first check to see if their is actually input but using the empty() function.  With adding the ! to empty() what happens is that the if statement is being asked if $_POST['rtxt_article'] is NOT empty, meaning that there is at least once character in it.

```
if (!empty($_POST['rtxt_article']) && trim(strip_tags($_POST['rtxt_article']))) {
  // do something
}
```

If for some reason it is still being passed with the new line character, then you could scrub the $_POST var first.

---

edited:

```
$var = trim($_POST['rtxt_article']);
if (!empty($var)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: By the way, i have !empty(..) checked before getting into the trim/strip_tags. Actually, trim/strip_tags was inside the !empty() if block.

Comment: No you don't.  trim() and strip_tags() has no way to check if a field is empty.

Comment: I meant i have it in the source code. I will try your method by adding && instead of nested if.

Comment: Made an edit for a cleaner way to do what your asking.  May help for clarification.

Comment: Still, didn't help. Thanks anyway.